# Loading excel file into R

Tags: r

I've tried to load an excel file into R.
I received the error message

```
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘lifecycle’"
```

I tried to install.package("lifecycle") and received the following error message:

install.packages("lifecycle")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/paula/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘cli’, ‘rlang’

There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
binary source needs_compilation
cli        3.2.0  3.6.1              TRUE
rlang      1.0.2  1.1.2              TRUE
lifecycle  1.0.1  1.0.4             FALSE

installing the source packages ‘cli’, ‘rlang’, ‘lifecycle’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/cli_3.6.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 567293 bytes (553 KB)
downloaded 553 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/rlang_1.1.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 763521 bytes (745 KB)
downloaded 745 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/lifecycle_1.0.4.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 107656 bytes (105 KB)
downloaded 105 KB

- installing *source* package 'cli' ...
  ** package 'cli' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
  ERROR: cannot remove earlier installation, is it in use?
- removing 'C:/Users/paula/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/cli'
- restoring previous 'C:/Users/paula/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/cli'
  Warning in file.copy(lp, dirname(pkgdir), recursive = TRUE, copy.date = TRUE) :
  problem copying C:\Users\paula\OneDrive\Documents\R\win-library\4.0\00LOCK-cli\cli\libs\x64\cli.dll to C:\Users\paula\OneDrive\Documents\R\win-library\4.0\cli\libs\x64\cli.dll: Permission denied
  Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘cli’ had non-zero exit status
- installing *source* package 'rlang' ...
  ** package 'rlang' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
  ERROR: cannot remove earlier installation, is it in use?
- removing 'C:/Users/paula/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/rlang'
- restoring previous 'C:/Users/paula/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/rlang'
  Warning in file.copy(lp, dirname(pkgdir), recursive = TRUE, copy.date = TRUE) :
  problem copying C:\Users\paula\OneDrive\Documents\R\win-library\4.0\00LOCK-rlang\rlang\libs\x64\rlang.dll to C:\Users\paula\OneDrive\Documents\R\win-library\4.0\rlang\libs\x64\rlang.dll: Permission denied
  Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rlang’ had non-zero exit status
- installing *source* package 'lifecycle' ...
  ** package 'lifecycle' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
  ** using staged installation
  ** R
  ** inst
  ** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
  Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) :
  namespace 'rlang' 1.0.2 is being loaded, but >= 1.1.0 is required
  Calls:  ... withCallingHandlers -> loadNamespace -> namespaceImport -> loadNamespace
  Execution halted
  ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'lifecycle'
- removing 'C:/Users/paula/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/lifecycle'
  Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘lifecycle’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
‘C:\Users\paula\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpu6O9OS\downloaded_packages’

What I've tried so far:

```
install.packages("lifecycle")
library(lifecycle)
```

Unfortunately I still receive the same error message.

Any ideas?
Thank you!

Comment: If your `library(lifecycle)` fails after installing it, it is almost certain that something in the output from the installation attempt indicates what the problem is. Please copy the code from (including) the `install.packages("lifecycle")` code on your console all the way down to the next prompt where you attempt to load it, then [edit] your question and paste that text into a [code block]. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Read and write excel with `readxl` and `writexl`.
For non-tabular data, `tidyxl`.

https://readxl.tidyverse.org/

https://docs.ropensci.org/writexl/

https://nacnudus.github.io/tidyxl/